# Help with MVC3 Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need some help with how to use the Html.DropDownListFor in MVC3 since the documentation is just crazy bad and I'm not finding the answer I need on here.

I have the following models

```
public class Users
{
     public virtual User_Roles RoleID {get; set;}
     public virtual string UserName{get; set;}
     ... more stuff
}

public class User_Roles
{
    public virtual Int32 RoleID {get; set;}
    public virtual string Role {get; set;}
}
```

My page (create_user.cshtml) looks like this:

```
@model Users
... stuff
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoleID)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleID, Model.RoleID.Role, Model.RoleID.RoleID)
```

It keeps throwing the error `"'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Users>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor'"`

Can anyone explain to me how I can pull the list of role names and IDs from the DB since this clearly is not the way to do it?

Comment: I can't see in your model any collection type. A dropdown list requires a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass items of dropdown using `SelectList`.

Make sure you retrieve Roles in `ViewBag.Roles` from controller.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Id", "Name"), "")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! I keep forgetting that a ViewBag can be more than just a string.